# Displaying today's birthdays

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to display the usernames of the users who are having their birthday.
The birthdays are stored in the database as DATE in the column `birthdays`.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
function birthday_today(){
    $current_date = date('m-d');
    $row = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `birthday` FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW())");
    if (date('m-d', strtotime($row['birthday'])) == date('m-d')) {
        return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $row['username'], '</li></ul>');
    }
}
echo birthday_today();
?>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be echoing anything. I've tried several different ways of putting the data into an echo but no success so far. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: can you use var_dump($row); give the output, it will be better to solve it exactly why not giving any results

Comment: var_dump outputs this: resource(17) of type (mysql result)

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `birthday` FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW())");
if (!$result) {
  die('error in query '.$sql.' error is: '.mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
now var_dump($row);

Comment: Just noticed that I also put the ) in the wrong place after implode. Fixing that does not fix my problem though :P

Comment: The correct answer is already below, but why are you using an `if` statement? If you get the correct rows from the database, you don't have to check again in php.

Comment: var_dump outputs this: array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "kenny" ["username"]=> string(5) "kenny" [1]=> string(10) "2015-05-25" ["birthday"]=> string(10) "2015-05-25" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do this:

```
<?php
// just returns the users having a birthday
function birthday_today() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW())");
    $users = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $users[] = $row['username'];
    return $users;
}

// make a unordered-list out of the users having birthday
$ul = "<ul>";
foreach(birthday_today() as $username)
    $ul .= "<li>$username</li>";
$ul .= "</ul>";

echo $ul;
?>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working after all. When it's more than just one user's birthday, there is still only one username displayed.

Comment: @SandervanHommelen There is no logical nor syntax error in the code above, however, if you want more investigations post an excerpt of the table.

Comment: The exact problem is that, when there are no birthdays, the argument in foreach() is invalid and I get an error. Other than that the code works fine now. I suppose I'll need to work around that using some if-statement?

Comment: I fixed it using this after my query in the function and then just using echo birthday_today(); where I want it placed on the page: if(mysql_num_rows($row) == 0) {
   $result .= "No birthdays today.";
  } else {
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
    if (date('m-d', strtotime($result['birthday'])) == date('m-d')) {
     $users[] = $result['username'];
    }
   }
   $result .= "<ul>";
   foreach ($users as $user) {
    $result .= "<li>" . $user . "</li>";
   }
   $result .= "</ul>";
  }
 return $result;

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract the array from the result.

```
$users = array();
$row = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `birthday` FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW())");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($row)) {
    if (date('m-d', strtotime($result['birthday'])) == date('m-d')) {
        $users[] = $result['username'];
    }
}



// output results
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($users as $user) {
   echo "<li>".$user['username']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>"
```

Comment: This works, but only as long as there actually are birthdays. When it's nobody's birthday, I get an error saying that the argument in foreach() is invalid.

Comment: @SandervanHommelen The `if` statement is non-sense and redundant, since the birthdays of today are already out using the SQL query!!

Comment: someOne is correct, although this won't make a difference apart from maybe slowing it down slightly. By KISS standards, you should remove the if statement.